# Considering Autocompletion. How to tell Geany in which directories to look for header files?

Tags: c++, autocomplete, geany

I am coming from KDE to XFCE and hence arrive from KDevelop at Geany. I have no plans of using Geany for any compilation stuff, prefering to write my own CMakeLists.txt files. However, what I loved about KDevelop and dearly would have again:

In KDevelop I could "attach" an include-directory to a c++ file meaning that code autocompletion would look for #included headers within that directory and use its content.

For example it was possible to "attach" something like */usr/share/myIncludes/*
containing "my_foo.h". Then in the source code of my program I would

```
#include "my_foo.h"
```

and henceforth auto-completion would kick in using the contents of "my_foo.h".

I find this surprisingly hard to google. Is there even a feature like that in Geany, and if so, how would one use it?

My Geany is a simple install (geany and geany-common) on a clean (no non-free stuff) Debian System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geany is not supporting dynamic parsing of header files due to the performances and resources impact it would have.

However, you can generate a tag file from your headers as described inside [manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#generating-a-global-tags-file) or maybe use a plugin like [geanyctags](http://plugins.geany.org/geanyctags.html) or [projectorganizer](http://plugins.geany.org/projectorganizer.html) (recently rename from gproject)  which could help you there

Also you can find tag-files inside the [wiki](http://wiki.geany.org/tags/start) which you can import via the Tools-menu.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. geany -g test.tags /opt/myIncludes/* led to an "unknown extension error for 'test.tags'" even though tags was the extension even in the example in your 'manual' link. I accept your answer nonetheless since this hint actually aims at what I want. I am afraid I won't spend too much more time on it though... by now and after reading some more forum texts I have decided to blow my own pretexts to the winds and installed kdevelop on xfce after all. Working fine for some hours now. And even though phonon threatened sound trouble even after a reboot still all seems fine.

Comment: Please try to call your file something like test.c.tags